# remove output header and footer when running a grunt command

Tags: npm, gruntjs, node-modules

I'm running a `grunt` command but it is displaying a header and footer that I want to remove.

This is my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        exec: {
            ls: {
                command: 'ls -la',
                stdout: true,
                stderr: true,
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
    grunt.registerTask('ls', ['exec:ls']);
}
```

and this is what I get:

**[EDIT]**

I got confused on the highlighted header on the image below. I wanted to highlight:

```
Running "exec:ls" (exec) task
```

[image]

Is there maybe some option I can use inside the target to remove that (yellow highlighted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header `Running "exec:ls" (exec) task` can be omitted by installing [grunt-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-reporter)

**Gruntfile.js**

Your `Gruntfile.js` can be configured as follows:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    reporter: {
      exec: {
        options: {
          tasks: ['exec:ls'],
          header: false
        }
      }
    },

    exec: {
      ls: {
        command: 'ls -la',
        stdout: true,
        stderr: true
      }
    }
  });

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.registerTask('ls', [
    'reporter:exec', //<-- The call to the reporter must be before exec.
    'exec:ls'
  ]);
}
```

**Note**: `grunt-reporter` is not loaded using `grunt.loadNpmTasks(...)`. Instead it utilizes [load-grunt-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-grunt-tasks). This will also handle the loading of `grunt-exec` too, so there's no need to `grunt.loadNpmTasks(...)` any other modules.

---

**But what about `Done` ?**

Unfortunately `grunt-reporter` does not provide a feature for omitting the final `Done` message.

To omit `Done` you have to resort to completing replacing `grunt`'s internal `grunt.log.success` function with an empty function. This approach is not particularly nice as its somewhat a hack. For example you could add the following to the top of your config:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.log.success = function () {}; // <-- Add this before grunt.initConfig({...})

  // ...

}
```

The same hack could also be used for the header too, however `grunt-reporter` is IMO a cleaner approach. I.e.

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.log.header = function () {}; // <-- Blocks all header logs.

  // ...

}
```